# how to add bootstrap form group on click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi I am new to jquery I had bootstrap modal having a form group and an add button now I want to add functionality as everytime I click add button the form group should add using jquery can anyone help me for this please help me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" >
      <div class="modal-body">
         <h3>Share with people</h3>
         <form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
         <div class="form-group">
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">choose an email for whome you want to share</option>
  </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">View only</option>
  </select>
    </div>


          <p style="color:red;display:none;" id="errUsr">Please select atleast one email, to share.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
      <label class="checkbox-inline container1">
      <input type="checkbox" value="" id="notif" style="margin-left: -10px;"  checked> &nbsp;&nbsp;Notify people
      <span class="checkmark">
</span>
      </label>
               <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right;margin-right: 50px;"></i>

         </div>

         <div class="form-group ">
          <textarea class="form-control shrMsg" placeholder="Message" id="shrMsg" style="margin-left: 3px; width:98%;"></textarea>
         </div>
          <div class="form-group shrBtns">
          <input type="hidden" id="hdn_tmId" value="0" />
          <input type="hidden" id="uname" value="0" />
          <input type="hidden" id="tname" value="0" />
           <input type="hidden" id="oid" value="0" />
          <button class="btn btn-default shrBtn" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-left: 3px; " >Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary shrBtn"> Send</button>
          </div>
        
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>';

</body>
</html>
```

Actually in this snippet the two dropdowns are not coming side by side but in my browser it is coming now what I want is when I click on plus the another two dropdowns sideby side should add like evrytime I click that it should add can anyone help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Add additional input groups to Bootstrap modal

Ensure that the form tag encompasses all the inputs you would like to submit. Then you can create a function like the one below to append additional input groups to your form.

### See Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/hexzero/jsk2poew/

```html
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" onclick="addAddtionalEmail()"></i>
```

```js
const emaiList = [];
let emailListIndex = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {
  addAddtionalEmail();
  $("form").submit(function (e) {
    getEmailValueList();
    alert("Emai List: " + getEmailListString());
  });
});

function addAddtionalEmail() {
  if (emailListIndex < 9) {  // This is not performant, although should be good for this type application
    $("#email-list-container").append(   
      `<div class="form-group" style="display:flex">
              <select class="form-control" name="email" id="Email-${emailListIndex}">
                <option value="volvo">choose an email for whome you want to share</option>
              </select>
              <select class="form-control" style="margin-left:1rem" name="cars" id="Car-${emailListIndex}">
                <option value="volvo">View only</option>
              </select>
        </div>`
    );
    emailListIndex++;
  }
}

function getEmailValueList() {
  for (let i = 1; i < emailListIndex; i++) {
    emaiList.push({
      Email: $("#Email-" + i).val(),
      Car: $("#Car-" + i).val(),
    });
  }
}

function getEmailListString() {
  let result = "";
  emaiList.forEach((e) => {
    result += "\nEmai: " + e.Email + " Car: " + e.Car;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working for me onclick of add symbol and not getting an error please help me @ Axel Aldrich

Comment: @ Axel Aldrich I am not getting error and the code is not working for me

Comment: could you provide you code? Remove any sensitive details.

Comment: I just tried you code not more than that @ Axel Aldrich

Comment: You mean it does not run in the work in the browser when you click run code snippet?

Comment: Yes @Axel Amdrich

Comment: Well you must have a different browser then. I use chrome. Which one do you use?

Comment: Chrome only @ Axel Aldrich

Comment: Please provide more information. It is really hard for me to help. This code should run the same everywhere although I will try to post it in jsFiddle and see if that will work for you.

Comment: I have made a demo for you. Please check if it is working for you.

Comment: @ Axel ur fiddle is working see my fiddle once actually I had changed the dropdown like this and when I fill the once set of fileds only the add button should enable please once see this and help me

Comment: You did not provide a link. I can't check

Comment: @ Axel Aldrich yes it worked well thankyou last doubt I want search functionality for this dropdown could you please help me how can I do it for your code